# What is the correct POST format to request data from HerokuApp using Tokens?

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, postman, token

Scenario:  I'm trying to access an online calculator service from a Herokuapp. 
Problem: I'm a Heroku & Postman neophyte.

Here's a given url to the service:

```
Base URL: https://calculator-frontend-challenge.herokuapp.com
```

This is supposed to be a POST; so I'm also given the following:

```
POST /calculations
```

...which creates a new calculation: 
● Input: {} 
● Output:

```
{
"id": ​"ecc7ab90-0a59-4168-b1e5-b5cf63edf9fd"
}
```

Ok... so far, so good.

[image]

So I got the id generated and retrieved.

Now I'm trying to attach some tokens per instruction:

[image]

via Postman, I tried to add the 'tokens':
[image]

And ID: 
[image]
I'm lost here.  
I need the correct POST format to get something back from **herokuapp**.

This doesn't require the use of Postman.
I'm merely using it as a development tool.

Attached is the assignment per request.
I'm getting partial results but it's flaky.

[image]
[image]

Comment: *I'm trying to attach some tokens per instruction:* Where can I find this instructions? Is there any doc available?

Comment: I've added the assignment per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. You need to add the calculationId to the request path itself. It is not meant to be added as an Auth Header.
2. Tokens are meant to be sent as a json payload in the request body. They are not meant to be sent as query params.

Answer (score 0):

A `POST` command has a body, they don't typically use query params. It looks like you are supposed to hit the root endpoint to get an id that you will use afterwards, this is your response on the first call. Then, you are supposed to use a `POST` with an appropriate JSON body to build up your calculation.

```
POST https://calculator-frontend-challenge.herokuapp.com/calculations/ecc7ab90-0a59-4168-b1e5-b5cf63edf9fd/tokens
```

In your URLRequest, you can add your JSON body. Easiest way in Swift is to use a `Codable` type and then use a `JSONEncoder` to create the data.

```swift
struct TokenRequest: Codable {
    let type: TokenType
    let value: String

    enum TokenType: String, Codable {
        case operator
        case number
    }
}

let tokenRequest = TokenRequest(type: .number, value: "5")
var request = URLRequest(url: ...)
request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(tokenRequest)
```

You should read up on RESTful services to get a better handle on the basics of how/why this works.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
As of now, I didn't get this to work.

So I've sent this assignment aside;  perhaps return to it later.